# How can I subtract two columns contain Time but column datatype is VARCHAR in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

| Museum_id | day | open | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | sunday | 10:30AM | 05:30PM |
| 30 | Monday | 12:30PM | 07:10PM |

Table name: `Museum_hours`

Columns `open` and `close` both are defined as `VARCHAR`.

How can I subtract these two columns to get `open_hours` in SQL Server?

Comment: 12:30PM - A TYPO? IF 12:30AM then the timediff to 7:10PM will not be in exact hours so what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: You could use datediff: SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST('10:30AM' as datetime), CAST('05:30PM' as time)) -- change the HOUR to minute or whatever unit you might want.

Comment: @Sterner how would I do it with those columns? I am getting error.

SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(mh.open as datetime), CAST(mh.close as time))

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'open'

Comment: @P.Salmon yes maybe

Comment: open is a reserved word , if that is indeed your column name you need to enclose with square brackets. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8#bmdaidxsqln_p

Comment: `open` and `close` are reserved words for cursors and should be avoided as column names, you'll need to delimit (`[open]`) them. I'd use `OpenTime` and `CloseTime` then you don't need to add square brackets until the end of time.

Comment: I have tried that before
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(mh.[open] as datetime), CAST(mh.[close] as time)) from museum_hours mh

I did that, it is showing error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: If you are getting "Conversion failed", then I assume you have some bad time data that is not able to be formatted into a datetime/time. Such as: 0710PM -- that will fail as there is no colon to form a time from.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to subtract the time:

declare @open varchar(10) = '10:30AM';

select datepart(hour,convert(time, @open));

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the hours *rounded-up* using a combination of `CONVERT(TIME, ...)`, `DATEDIFF(minutes, ...)`, and `CEILING(.../60.0)`. A partial hour will convert to a fraction that is then rounded up.

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONVERT(TIME, [open]) AS OpenTime,
    CONVERT(TIME, [close]) AS CloseTime,
    DATEDIFF(
        minute,
        CONVERT(TIME, [open]),
        CONVERT(TIME, [close])
        ) AS Minutes,
    CONVERT(INT, CEILING(DATEDIFF(
        minute,
        CONVERT(TIME, [open]),
        CONVERT(TIME, [close])
        ) / 60.0)) AS HoursRoundedUp
FROM MuseumData
```

(The OpenTime, CloseTime, and Minutes select items are only present to  show the intermediate results.)

Results:

| Museum_id | day | open | close | OpenTime | CloseTime | Minutes | HoursRoundedUp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | sunday | 10:30AM | 05:30PM | 10:30:00 | 17:30:00 | 420 | 7 |
| 30 | Monday | 12:30PM | 07:10PM | 12:30:00 | 19:10:00 | 400 | 7 |
| 30 | Tuesday | 10:30AM | 10:00PM | 10:30:00 | 22:00:00 | 690 | 12 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0AL310Lp).

If you have a need to deal with late night hours that cross midnight like open 11:00AM and close 02:00AM (15 hours), you may need to adjust the calculated minutes something like with `(calculatedMinutes + 1440) % 1440 AS AdjustedMinutes`. (1440 is the number of minutes in a day.) This would adjust a calculated -540 minutes value (-9 hours) to +900 minutes (15 hours). See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t1J3Y4vr).